# Move "Default welcome msg!" from right to left Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, frontend

I'm trying to move the "Default welcome msg!" from the top bar on the right side, where is now, to the left side, so this way I have just the login, account ecc links on the right, and just the message on the left.
I'm using Luma theme, on Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Create default.xml under your theme :**

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

**Add below code in XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="authorization-link-login" destination="header.links" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Override below file in your theme :**

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/module.less

**In your theme:**

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/module.less

**Replace below lines:**

*Line No.: 93 to 119*

```
.header.panel {
    > .header.links {
        .lib-list-inline();
        font-size: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: @indent__base;
        width: 100%;

        > li {
            font-size: @font-size__base;
            margin: 0 0 0 15px;

            > a {
                .lib-link(
                @_link-color: @header-panel__text-color,
                @_link-text-decoration: none,
                @_link-color-visited: @header-panel__text-color,
                @_link-text-decoration-visited: none,
                @_link-color-hover: @header-panel__text-color,
                @_link-text-decoration-hover: underline,
                @_link-color-active: @header-panel__text-color,
                @_link-text-decoration-active: underline
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Line No.: 551 to 598*

```
.header {
    &.panel {
        > .header.links {
            .lib-list-inline();
            margin-left: auto;

            > li {
                margin: 0;
                float: right;

                &.welcome,
                > a {
                    float: left;
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 1.4;
                }

                &.welcome {
                    a {
                        .lib-css(color, @color-white);
                        .lib-css(padding-left, @indent__xs);
                    }
                }
            }

            > .authorization-link {
                float: right;
                &:after {
                    content: attr(data-label);
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin: 0 @indent__xs 0 @indent__xs;
                }
            }

            > .customer-welcome + .authorization-link {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }

    &.content:extend(.abs-add-clearfix-desktop all) {
        padding: @indent__l @indent__base 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam Yes this is working